# Steam Failure An error occurred while updating Count-Strike 2 (missing executable)

Tags: macos, steam

I just download Counter-Strike 2 via the Steam on my MacBook Air M2, 2022 and when I'm trying to start it, I'm getting following error:

[image: Failure]

Please advise.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: CS2 is [not available for Mac](https://esports.gg/guides/counter-strike-2/counter-strike-2-mac/) - it looks like it's tried to download a Windows version - *"win64/cs2.exe"* is not a Mac binary. [Video games are also off-topic here, sorry].

Comment: @Tetsujin I download it via Steam, Steam should NOT let me download Windows variant instead of Mac due to compatibility. I guess Steam didn't tag this title as Windows only. Sucks, I was so looking forward to play a bit, remember the good old days)) sorry for posting about video game, didn't realized it was off-topic here, sorry.

Comment: @alexus - Well, Steam is allowing it, and the executable does not appear to be a compatible executable with your machine. The path clearly indicates Windows, x64, instead of the very least ARM.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the application doesn’t support the author’s machine

Comment: *Steam should NOT let me download Windows variant instead of Mac due to compatibility*... Because there's no native version and when you have Proton enabled it'll, as always, use the Windows version. The thing is it doesn't work for ARM based devices such as yours, hence the error.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't have "Proton" enabled (whatever that is). I have few other games and all of those games one cannot download due to incompatibility, CS2 is the first one that I can download even though it's clearly incompatible.

Comment: That being the case it must be a Steam's error. But you're strongly advised to check Steam Settings > Compatibility and confirm "Enable Steam Play for all other titles" ISN'T selected because if it is that's Proton, FYI. And if enabled your problem is two-fold, all non-MacOs native games that are listed as compatible with the emulation can be downloaded but hardly any will actually run in Apple silicon, they expect x86_64.

Comment: @ChanganAuto again, I'm _NOT_ using Proton yet however definitely looks like something worth to explore))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I greatly appreciate everyone's comments. I apologize for off-topic question here, however since there is *some* traction w/ my question, I would like to share the following with everyone:

[Mac CSGO Solution! Come Here! :: Counter-Strike 2 General Discussions](https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/3881596897258134490/)

WARNING: I have *NOT* tested it ... yet)

---

The following may be also an interesting:

- [Game Porting Toolkit - Gaming on M1 Apple silicon Macs and MacBooks, bugs, fixes, compatiblity and troubleshooting guides - AppleGamingWiki](https://www.applegamingwiki.com/wiki/Game_Porting_Toolkit)
- [ValveSoftware/Proton: Compatibility tool for Steam Play based on Wine and additional components](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton#the-easy-way)